# Grinding down my endmill/drill/rotary bit's shank

Tags: sanding, power-tools, router-bit, drill-bits

I have another router with a 1/4" collet. I want to be able to use my 3/8" shank CNC endmill on it.

So I'm thinking of grinding the shank to 1/4". Here's how I'm gonna do it:

I'll put copious amount of tape on the cut length so it won't get damaged as I hold that cut length side to the chuck of my power drill. Then, I'll run the power drill while having a piece of sandpaper grip the shank. Lastly, I'll stop when I reach the required shank diameter.

Assuming this could potentially work, what sand paper grit is best to grind HSS? I'm presuming silicon carbide?

Can I use this method to grind down large endmill/drill/rotary bits shanks for smaller collets/chucks?

Comment: Sorry to rain on this parade as well but while this is technically feasible (just in the most basic outline) you're not going to get the required concentric accuracy in possibly any power drill in the world. Most drill presses aren't accurate enough. But even if they were, how are you going to measure it? Do you have a micrometer? Cos you need one! With any ponderings in this arena please remember the rotation speeds you're dealing with, routers aren't 'merely' 10x a typical drill's max speed, they could be 25-30 times faster! Don't underestimate what that energy is capable of.

Comment: Perhaps a better plan would be to research affordable but still decent router bits in the shaft diameters you need? Sorry we can't formally help with this sort of query here because shopping Qs are specifically against the rules, but there *are* non-name brand bits out there from a few sources with consistently high user scores so it wouldn't be a fruitless search I assure you.

Comment: If your application can do it (I don’t know if you’re in a home cnc situation), a 1/2” collet router with a reducer would let you use that bit safely.